# How to trace where Magento is calling templates from?

Tags: php, magento, layout

I'm working with Magento. See the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

Is there an easy way to find where HTML resides. I.e. is there some kind of trace I can use?

Answer (score 14):

In the admin go to *System > Configuration > Developer*, pick a store from the "Configuration Scope" select in the top left corner, then there will be a new option in "Debug" section called "Template Path Hints". Turn this on and refresh your store page again.

This and more is explained in [the Designer's Guide to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide).

Answer (score 6):

I fully agree with the [answer of clockworkgeek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177874/how-to-trace-where-magento-is-calling-templates-from/4177950#4177950) - the easiest way is to turn on *Template Path Hints* in *System -> Configuration -> Developer* section of admin panel (scope of your store must be chosen for this field to appear). After that all your store pages will be rendered with inclusions of red panels, showing the path to templates.

Nice addition is also to turn on *Add Block Names to Hints* in the mentioned above admin section - so you'll also see block names serving that templates.

These actions will allow you to easily trace 95% of all design.

However, there are also some blocks that do not render phtml. Or they overload standard *toHtml*() method in such a way that it doesn't show template's path. These are more complicated cases. To find the place where design is created you should either:

1. Learn layout-blocks-phtml model of View part in Magento - [Designer's Guide to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide) is a good place to study it. Then you'll be able to find blocks and templates by layout structure.
2. Install X-Debug, set it up for your IDE, set a breakpoint at `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` line and dig in this line. It's the easiest and most universal way to solve your problem (although knowledge of Magento design structure still is a must).