# Magento product view file

Tags: php, magento

In magento product `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` I have

```
getchildhtml('container1','',true, true);
getchildhtml('container2','',true,true);
```

By this I get the custom options drop down.

What are `container1` and `container2` and from where do they render?

Answer (score 0):

The `getChildHTML()` function is contained in http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php

From looking at the source code, it is looking for something that was previously assigned as "container1" or "container2". It looks like this is set with the `setChild()` function contained in that same file.

Now as far as where the verbage "container1" and "container2" come from, I think it comes from the layout, as seen in this bit of source: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.4/app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/catalog.xml

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
   <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
   <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
   <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
   <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the catalog.xml file in the design>frontend>base>default>layout>catalog.xml you will see the definition of the container1 and container2.

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
```

The block type "core/template_facade" is the class Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade

You can also turn on the template hint in the Admin. Have look at this for information how to do it: [How to trace where Magento is calling templates from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177874/how-to-trace-where-magento-is-calling-templates-from)

Comment: wow man tuong le tats g8 of u keep in touch as iam a beginner in magento :-) really hlpd me by tat hints